# check if value exists before adding to result array

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through some data, and creating a new array, like so:

```
var tableData = [],
countries = {};
fullData.forEach(function (d) {
    d.gdp = +d.gdp;
    var country = countries[d.country];
    if (!country) {
        tableData.push(country = countries[d.country] = {});
    }
    country[d.year] = d.value + " <span class='note'>" + d.note + "</span>", 
        countries[d.country]['note'] = d.note,
        countries[d.country]['GDP'] = d.gdp,
        countries[d.country].Country = d.country;
});
```

I only want to include d.note if it's a value. There are lots of objects in the data that don't have this field. Where do I put the conditional for this? I keep getting errors. Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I've read this several times now and re-formatted all your code and I'm still not 100% sure what your asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace this line

```
country[d.year] = d.value + " <span class='note'>" + d.note + "</span>", 
  countries[d.country]['note'] = d.note,
        countries[d.country]['GDP'] = d.gdp,
    countries[d.country].Country = d.country;
```

with

```
if ( d.note )
{
  country[d.year] = d.value + " <span class='note'>" + d.note + "</span>";
  countries[d.country]['note'] = d.note;
}
countries[d.country]['GDP'] = d.gdp;
countries[d.country].Country = d.country;
```